# Seems some key bindings don't work with TigerVNC on Windows 10 with Kali linux (Kex)

Tags: linux, windows-10, wsl2, dwm, tigervnc

I am running Linux in WSL on Windows 10.

The Linux distribution is Kali.

I am using Win-Kex.

I installed the Window Manager dwm from Suckless.

But for some reason some of the key bindings don't seem to work.

So to move a window in dwm I press the window key + shift key + (number) a number from 1 to 9 (those are called tags).

But for some reason I can only move windows to 1, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9.

So it doesn't work for 2, 3, 6.

Unsure why.

I am able to go to all the tags: window key + (number)

Could it be that TigerVNC is confused about the key binding or Windows 10 or could it be something else?

I am using dwm on my personal laptop (bare metal), and I don't have any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying to debug my situation with xev (print contents of X events), I figured out my issue.

I have my Windows 10 keyboard layout setup for the french (Canada).

French Canada:

- shift + 2 = "
- shift + 3 = /
- shift + 6 = ?

English Canada/US:

- shift + 2 = @
- shift + 3 = #
- shift + 6 = ^

So when I was pressing *window key + shift + 2* the system was getting the wrong keyboard output because it was expecting the English version output.

I tried with an English Canada keyboard layout and everything worked.